# Having to double click to update width of window in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label, window-resize

I'm working on a program in my spare time that automatically generates a Pascal Triangle where the number of rows in the triangle depend on a user input.

The problem I have is that as the inputs increase the outputs eventually "leak" over the sides of the window. To fix this I wrote this:

```
def resize_window():
    newWidth = app.outPut.winfo_width()
    if (newWidth > 275):
        root.geometry(str(newWidth) + "x400+" + screenMid)
    if (newWidth < 275):
        root.geometry("275x400+" + screenMid)
```

This changes the width of the windows depending on the width of the output, the problem is that the value of newWidth is always one value behind. For example if the label was 10 pixels wide and I input something into it that makes it 14 I would still get 10, but then if I was to do something that makes it 12 I would then get 14 and so on.

Is there any better way to get the pixel width of a label in tkinter?

EDIT:

I found an answer to the question I made the following changes to the code:

```
def resize_window():
    root.update_idletasks()
    newWidth = app.outPut.winfo_width()
    if (newWidth > 275):
        root.geometry(str(newWidth) + "x400+" + screenMid)
    if (newWidth < 275):
        root.geometry("275x400+" + screenMid)
```